# Why Is My New File Not Added To A Pycharm Project

Tags: pycharm

I have a project in Pycharm.  While in this project in Pycharm I use "New" to make a second file named X.  This file contains

```
class X:
```

In my original file I have the line

```
from X import X
```

when I execute the original file I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asdf/Documents/4D/Python/torii.py", line 59, in <module>
    from X import X
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X'
```

I don't understand why this new file isn't automatically added to the project.  I have added new files to the project before without problems.  Given this problem, I don't know how to add the file to the project.

Comment: Go to Settings >> Project Settings, and set the folder to which both files are in as a 'src' folder. This allows Python to run relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

They are both in the same folder. I found out that the X file was not a Python file, as I intended and believed I had chosen.